# Facelets Taglib outside WEB-INF directory?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, taglib, jsf-2.2

I am trying to create a facelets taglib. Every tutorial I read so far tells to place the `*.taglib.xml` file and the tag files themselves inside the `WEB-INF` directory, but none actually says why. If I try to move the tag files to another directory and update the `*.taglib.xml` to point to the moved files I get the following `TagException`:

```
/confirmation/fields/ordersearchalternatives.xhtml @33,42 <s:orderSearchAlternatives> null

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /confirmation/fields/ordersearchalternatives.xhtml @33,42 <s:orderSearchAlternatives> null
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:144)
  at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
```

The same happens if the `*.taglib.xml` file is moved to another directory and the `web.xml` points to that.

It only seems to work if the tags' XHTML files and the taglib descriptor are inside the `WEB-INF` directory. What I would like to achieve is to have the taglib descriptor as well as the tags' XHTML files inside e.g. the `resources` directory and have the `web.xml` file pointing to it.

- Is that possible?
- Is that completely out of best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps someone else: Stumbling over [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339830/overview-of-all-jsf-related-web-xml-context-parameter-names-and-values) I figured out how to host my taglibs outside the `WEB-INF` directory. The `javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES` context param in `web.xml` tells JSF to look for one or more specific `.taglib.xml` file(s) in the given locations. The directories are all relative to the `web` directory.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
  <param-value>/shared/taglibs/y.taglib.xml;/other/taglibs/x.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```