# Send HTTP 400 error when <f:viewParam required> has failed on @NotNull property

Tags: validation, jsf, omnifaces, http-status-code-400, viewparams

I'm creating a JSF 2.2 page that requires a GET parameter to display data but I'm having difficult to enforce that parameter.

I also tried to use [Omnifaces's viewParam](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam) without success, I don't know what to try anymore.

I also found a [similar issue on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662202/notnull-bean-validation-ignored-for-viewparam) and I tried all suggestions...

When I open:

- `http://url-to/required-test.xhtml?test=foo`

It works correctly, `Param is: foo` is displayed.

But when I open:

- `http://url-to/required-test.xhtml?test=`
- `http://url-to/required-test.xhtml`

`Param is: null!` is displayed instead of a validation error message. And `null!` is only displayed because I added a special outputText only for this test, on the real application it would cause a NullPointerException somewhere.

How do I make the `required` attribute on `<f:viewParam />` or `<o:viewParam />` work?

My test code:

**required-test.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="test" value="#{requiredTestBean.value}" required="true" />
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
    <title>Required Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    Param is:
    <h:outputText value="#{requiredTestBean.value}" rendered="#{requiredTestBean.value != null}" />
    <h:outputText value="null!" rendered="#{requiredTestBean.value == null}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

**RequiredTestBean.java**

```
package test;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RequiredTestBean
{
    @NotNull
    private String value;

    @NotNull
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(@NotNull String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Context params on **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CLIENT_WINDOW_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Where is the `<h:message>` which should show the validation error message?

Comment: @BalusC I already resolved the problem with your answer on an other question, thanks ;P . I didn't know that the validation error was going to be displayed on `<h:message />` when I asked, I was expecting the server to show a `HTTP 400 Bad Request` error page informing the validation error. `<o:viewParamValidationFailed sendError="400" />` solved that.

Comment: Ah ok, the initial question didn't make your expectations clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incredible how I search for a solution for hours and I find it 20 minutes after asking this question...

I just replaced the view param tag with:

```
<o:viewParam name="test" value="#{requiredTestBean.value}" required="true">
    <o:viewParamValidationFailed sendError="400" />
</o:viewParam>
```

And it worked perfectly.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29841384/804976