# How do I troubleshoot broken includes in a JSF project?

Tags: jsf, uiinclude

I need to merge the work of two developers in a JSF project. One changed the directory structure, the other changed content.

In my current merge result, some `<ui:include />` statements seem broken. Firefox shows the message "The page isn't redirecting properly". I already experienced this message caused by broken includes, so I assume the same cause here. But that time I was the one who changed structure *and* content and changes were smaller, so it was easier to find where the erroneous include was.

This time, changes are much more and much more complex, so searching all the diffs for suspicious changes will be very time-consuming.

Even without this high-volume high-complexity case, I would like to have a general approach for troubleshooting broken includes.

There are no include-related messages in my logs. Are there some good logging settings for that ?
JSF implementation currently used is MyFaces.

Comment: start by running you application in development mode. It will show things that are otherwise not visible. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339830/overview-of-all-jsf-related-web-xml-context-parameter-names-and-values

Comment: A good IDE should help too - intelliJ can point those out.

Comment: well ... the situation is even more complex. In my project, I need to build variants of the webapp. My sources are organized in some subdirectories base/, variant1/, variant2/, ... (all at the same level). During the build process of a specific variant, its files are merged with base. Additionally, some of the includes are variable-dependent, like: include src="/path/to/#{sessionBean.someVariable}/file.xhtml". Therefore I'm afraid that only runtime-analysis can help.