# JSF 2.2 misspelled redirect doesn't generate an error

Tags: redirect, jsf-2.2

I'm converting an app written in JSF 1.1/ADF faces to JSF 2.2 (Mojarra) /Primefaces and converting all of the faces-config navigations to inplace (implicit?).

I just spent two hours debugging why the redirect:

```
"blahbla?faces-redirect=true"
```

wasn't working. Turns out it was supposed to be

```
"blahblah?faces-redirect=true"
```

I'm not sure why I didn't get some sort of error. Web developer didn't show anything, nothing in the logs - and my logs are working fine. The only indication was a lack of an error message but nothing redirecting.

Searching, I found only this

> You only need to keep in mind that the new JSF 2.0 provided implicit
>   navigation doesn't scan for the presence of the file,...

[Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

I guess I expected a "404" type of error if the redirect page didn't exist. I told the server to display a page that doesn't exist, so some error must of raised and then discarded somewhere?

Is there some setting - maybe in web.xml - that will help display this type of coding error? Or anything else?

I just need it for dev.

PS. I did check the file name by copying it from the code and pasting it into the term but I made the mistake of using tab completion and of course it completed. If I had just put .xhtml on the end I would have seen the missing char.

if it helps, I'm running Tomcat 7

Comment: tried setting the application project state to development mode while developing? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339830/overview-of-all-jsf-related-web-xml-context-parameter-names-and-values

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for reminding me about that! I had turned it back to Production at some point to check out another matter. I put it back to Development (where it should be) and that did not make a difference. It was worth asking this question just to get that reminder.