# f:validateRegex always checked when deploy a jsf2.1 project into weblogic12c

Tags: jsf, primefaces, weblogic12c

I am going to deploy a jsf2.1(jsf2.1+spring3+primface-3.0.M3) project to weblogic 12c(jdk1.8).

Its a long story to make it work in weblogic12c,but there are still some problems,such as <f:validateRegex component, it always checked no matter whether there is empty or not,but it works fine in weblogic10.3.6(jdk1.7)

How can i fix it without change the pattern or other attributes?

My code:
`<f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9a-zA-Z;\s\r\*]+$" />`

My weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name>
            <package-name>net.sf.cglib.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.annotation.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.primefaces.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>

        <prefer-application-resources>
            <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.FacesConfigResourceProvider</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/resources/javax.faces/jsf.js</resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/resources/javax.faces/jsf-uncompressed.js</resource-name>           
        </prefer-application-resources>
        <!-- <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes> -->
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: With jBoss we use this configuration in web.xml: `<context-param><param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name><param-value>false</param-value></context-param>` so give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid validation of empty field you can add this parameter to your `web.xml` (works in jsf 2.1)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339830/overview-of-all-jsf-related-web-xml-context-parameter-names-and-values) you can find some explanation and many others parameters.